# ssis query on multiple databases

Tags: t-sql, ssis

We have a query that performs very slow, here is the scenerio:  Server A has the 'calling' database on it, Server B contains the databases to be queried (14 of them).  The same Stored Proc is used against all 14 DB's.  This is SQL Server 2012/SSIS, and the Server and DB's are dynamic via expressions in a loop.

The Stored Proc on A executes an INSERT INTO, drawing from a veiw located on the current DB on server B via Linked Sever.  Server B's view is drawn from multiple tables on the DB, actually UNIONING two sub views, each with many joins.  The question is, is there a batter way?, such as Execute the remote views into a _tmp table, fist and have the _tmp table on Server B waiting for Server A's INSERT?, or is there some magic SSIS 2010 has to overcome this?, etc?..

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Since you're using SSIS, wouldn't it be possible for you to directly extract data from the views/tables of your source databases, and then union the data in the SSIS data flow? This should perform better than using linked servers, especially when you execute queries containing joins across servers.

Comment: That is a very good point, just what I was looking for.  The views are complex, and build on views joining views..  ugh, horrible design, but it's a vendors product, we can't change it.  Extracting the views separatly is a good idea and handling the union in a flow I totally missed.  Thanks!